# Where do Latin and Greek words come from?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics

A lot of words in European and other languages come from Latin and Greek, if English (It's an example) words come from Latin and Greek, where Latin and Greek words come from?

Comment: There are a lot of words in English that are recognizably similar to words of Greek and Latin. But your question doesn't seem to be about English, it seems to be about the source of the words of Greek, and of Latin. Though you *might* be asking how words of Greek and Latin got into English (in which case you actually need to separate Greek from Latin since the answers is slightly different, depending on original language). So please rewrite the question so that we can tell what you are actually asking.

Comment: No, I just asked where Latin and Greek words come from. The origin of Latin and Greek words.

Comment: So is your question simply "Where do Latin and Greek words come from?", and this other stuff about other languages is actually irrelevant? That's simple enough to fix.

Comment: By the way, there are lots of words in English that don't come from Latin and Greek. At the time when Latin and Greek existed, the ancestor of English was already a separate language.

Comment: I think you should start with this video https://youtu.be/XTkf9bEB8RU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This graph gives you a decent picture of the evolution of Indo-European languages:

[image: Evolution of Indo-European Languages]

The first line under Proto-Indo-European would benefit from a "Proto-" prefix, though (Proto-Indo-Iranian, Proto-Hellenic, etc.)

Derivation and borrowing are two different phenomena. Kernel English words **derive** from Proto-Indo-European, via Proto-Germanic, West-Germanic, Anglo-Frisian, Old English and Middle English. Words that come from Latin and Greek (or French, Old Norse, Celtic, Arabic or Nahuatl) are **borrowings**. You can spot the difference because the normal transformations that apply to derived words do not apply to borrowings. For instance, initial Latin /p/ corresponds to English initial /f/:

> **P**ater - **F**ather
>
> **P**isces - **F**ish

But English *paternal*, with an initial /p/ - which means it was borrowed from Latin, at a time when the transformation p->f was no longer taking place.

Comment: A few more Indo-European roots and etymologies of English words that come from them. Note the differences between borrowings and direct descent: *_[gen-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf)_, *_[sed-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sed.pdf)_, *_[penkwe-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/penkwe.pdf)_, and *_[dei-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf)_.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, it should be noted there are a few missing branches on the second level of the tree: Anatolian, Tocharian, Armenian and Albanian.

Comment: @jlawler, may I ask the source of those excellent charts?

Comment: Thank you. I made them for my [freshman etymology class](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/). That was a while ago, but not much changes in etymology.

Comment: @jlawler I think your charts would make a great answer to this question.

Comment: "proto" meaning speculative, or inferred, or reconstructed or whatever, it it true that there is no non-proto between PIE and Greek/Latin?

Comment: @mobileink - Proto-Hellenic and Proto-Italic, I suppose. Also, there is possibly more than one layer between Greek / Latin and PIE; perhaps a proto-Italo-Celtic, perhaps a proto-European? See for instance http://dnghu.org/Indo-European/tag/proto-italic/ and http://wiki.verbix.com/Languages/Proto-Greek

Comment: thanks.  in any case, apparently no or little direct evidence of the direct common ancestor(s) of Greek and Latin?  All proto-something?

Answer (score 7):

Latin and Greek, just like English, are [Indo-European languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages): they're descended from an ancestor language called [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) (PIE), which we know relatively little about because it was spoken before the invention of writing. Many Latin and Greek words can be traced back to PIE, though others cannot (sometimes because they're borrowings from other languages, sometimes because their etymology is unknown).

Of course, your question can be taken a step further back -- where did Proto-Indo-European come from? The answer to that is that, although many people have speculated, no one really knows, because there isn't enough evidence to work with.

(Btw, many or most common English words do not come from Latin and Greek, but directly from Proto-Indo-European.)

Comment: Um -- not *directly* from PIE, but from PIE mostly via Proto-Germanic and Northwest Germanic, mostly from the Ingvaeonic - Anglo-Frisian line of West Germanic descent with a substantial later contribution from Old Norse in the North Germanic line of descent.

Comment: Is there any information about Proto-Indo-European or nothing?

Comment: @StoneyB: I would assume the "directly" in this answer means "by direct descent," not "immediately." There is an unbroken (unless you believe the "English is a creole" hypotheses) chain of transmission between PIE and inherited English words such as "fish."

Comment: @StoneyB I mean "directly" as opposed to "via borrowing" (which also excludes Old Norse loanwords).

Comment: @SherlockHolmes There is information but it is indirect. IE studies is a very large and active field -- see the Wikis article for a place to start.

Comment: What's IE? A linguistic research company?

Comment: @SherlockHolmes IE - Indo-Europen

Comment: A large number of Greek words do not "come from Indo-European", directly or otherwise, but are "pre-Greek".

Comment: @fdb You're right of course, and coincidentally I just had the same thought and edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: It must be telepathy.